# How to add using System.Reflection to all existing files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to add `System.Reflection` to all existing classes because I want to use `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` in all classes. But couldn't do this any other way other than opening all classes and adding it manually to the top. I don't have Reshaper. Tried to add the reference to the project but `System.Reflection` is not there to add. Please help me.

Is there a way for me to add

```
using System.Reflection
```

to all existing 119 classes without opening them one by one?

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.